# select thumbnail for share via url api on facebook mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I want to send a share to facebook out of a mobile app realised with phonegap and preselect the thumbnail which is shown.

With the url api this works for desktop browsers:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.nbapps.gokalender&p[images][0]=https%3A%2F%2Fg0.gstatic.com%2Fandroid%2Fmarket%2Fcom.nbapps.gokalender%2Fhi-256-0-263bba1f3af71252028742073efe586931aa3302
```

I would like to use the mobile facebook website instead, but as it seems the p array does not work with the mobile sharer.php:

```
https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.nbapps.gokalender&p[images][0]=https%3A%2F%2Fg0.gstatic.com%2Fandroid%2Fmarket%2Fcom.nbapps.gokalender%2Fhi-256-0-263bba1f3af71252028742073efe586931aa3302
```

As you can see I want to share a link to android market so there is not possibility to do anything server-side.

Is there a solution with url api or do I have to use the javascript SDK?